# When i set background image my buttons get hidden

Tags: java, user-interface

When I set the background image, my buttons and everything get hidden. The only thing I see is the image I chose.

This is the code I used:

```
this.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("image.jpg")));
```

Also, when I design a background, do I have to design it exactly on the size of my program?

Comment: Your image gets drawn over your buttons, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636170/jbutton-is-drawing-behind-an-image)

Comment: `setContentPane()` replaces the content.  Your code is doing exactly what you told it to.

Answer (score 2):

```
this.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("image.jpg")));
```

You can use a label as a background and then add components to the label. Your code should be something like this:

```
JLabel background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("image.jpg"));
background.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
background.add(...);
setContentPane( background );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use it the way you do the Contentpane isn't a container anymore!

For this you need to implement your own subclass of JComponent which overrides the paintComponent() method!